# JSON file data does not show when HTML page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

JSON File:

```
{ 
    "contactNumber":"12123123",
    "emailId":"info@sltscrs.com"
}
```

JQuery Code: it reads the file

```
$.getJSON('js/file.json', function (sc) {
     $('#phoneNumber').html('<span>'+sc.contactNumber+'</span>');
     $('#emailId').html('<span>'+sc.emailId+'</span>');
});
```

HTML Page: Displays the value

```
    <div class="spann2t">
                <ul class="logo-head2">
                    <li><h2 id="contactNumber"></h2></li>
     <li><p id="emailId"></p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

email id works. It shows the value. `contactNumber` does not show any value.

Answer (score 4):

You are using incorrect `id` to select cotact number `li`, change `$('#phoneNumber')` to `$('#contactNumber')` to get the `li`.

```js
var sc = {
  "contactNumber": "12123123",
  "emailId": "info@sltscrs.com"
};
$('#contactNumber').html('<span>' + sc.contactNumber + '</span>');
$('#emailId').html('<span>' + sc.emailId + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spann2t">
  <ul class="logo-head2">
    <li>
      <h2 id="contactNumber"></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p id="emailId"></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used anid that does not exist in your page in fact you put #phoneNumber instead of #contactNumber
Here is the correct code:

```
$.getJSON('js/file.json', function (sc) {
 $('#contactNumber').html('<span>'+sc.contactNumber+'</span>');
 $('#emailId').html('<span>'+sc.emailId+'</span>');
```

});

or

```
<div class="spann2t">
    <ul class="logo-head2">
        <li><h2 id="phoneNumber"></h2></li>
        <li><p id="emailId"></p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```